# html figure element: can figcaption be placed before img

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is it semantically/syntactically correct to have the `figcaption` element be positioned anywhere within the `figure` element?

Consider the following:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>Hello caption</figcaption>
  <img src="/path/to/file">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

- W3C: `figcaption` can be placed anywhere in `figure` (as child, not  descendant)
- WHATWG: `figcaption` can be placed as first or as last child of `figure`

#### W3C

[In **HTML5**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element), the `figcaption` element has to be the first or the last child of `figure`:

> Either: One `figcaption` element followed by flow content.
>   Or: Flow content followed by one `figcaption` element.
>   Or: Flow content.

[In **HTML 5.1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element), the `figcaption` element can be placed anywhere in the `figure` element:

> Flow content optionally including a `figcaption` child element.

[In **HTML 5.1** 2nd Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html51-20171003/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element), too.

[In **HTML 5.2** (Proposed REC)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/PR-html52-20171102/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element), too.

Here’s the issue about the change:
[Allow figcaption anywhere in a figure element?](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/177)

#### WHATWG

[In the **HTML Living Standard**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) (as of 2017-11-17), it’s the same as in HTML5:

> Either: One `figcaption` element followed by flow content.
>   Or: Flow content followed by one `figcaption` element.
>   Or: Flow content.